# Warning errors when firing YouTube popup video with MagnificPopup

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have recently discovered 2 warning errors, as issued by Google Chrome's Developer tools dashboard, with relation to my YouTube popup videos (that are rendered by the MagnificPopup script).

Is there anything we can do to fix, or simply out of our hands?

*The actual function and video rendering is still in tact, with no visible display issues -- but those two warnings are prompted when the YouTube video popup link is fired.

Attached is the screenshot of my Developer Tool's inspection pane:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrHQi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just warnings, I assume everything else is working as intended?

Comment: Yes, Erik.. Everything, by expected function, is still rendering properly. I just happed to be a stickler when it comes to an error or warning that might display in the developer's tools output. Thanks for your reply.